# How to implement a polling mechanism in angular which has to be called every interval of time?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, observable, angular7

How to implement a polling mechanism in Angular ?

I have an API call to subscribe which contains the data, the interval (in ms) at which it will be called again and the completed flag after which call has to be stopped.

On first call of API, 
we get the data in result,
we get the interval to call the API in result[0].requestInterval and 
we get the flag to stop calling API in result[0].requestComplete
if it is true, we have to stop calling API else call the API again

```
this.bookFlightService.GetFlights(this.baseUrl, searchResource, inboundDate)
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.callNo++;
                this.bookFlights = result as BookFlights[];
                this.requestComplete = this.bookFlights[0].complete;
                this.requestInterval = this.bookFlights[0].callAfterMs;
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
destructor$ = new Subject();

this.bookFlightService.GetFlights(this.baseUrl, searchResource, inboundDate).pipe(
  switchMap(response => timer(0, 1000)),
  tap(() => this.callNo++),
  switchMap(() => this.makeHttpCall()),
  takeUntil(this.destructor$),
  tap(response => { if(response.complete) this.destructor$.next(); }),
).subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

1 - create a subject to stop your stream when you want
2 - Make your Http call for the first time
3 - Change the stream to a timer (emits once, then every given ms)
4 - Increment your number of calls (original code)
5 - switch again your timer stream to a new call of your API
6 - take until the subject emits
7 - Emit on the destructor if needed

[Demo stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsnd8z)

Comment: Hi @trichetriche, your solution works good for one call. i.e when response[0].complete is true in the first call ! but when the response[0].complete is false for first call, we have unstoppable API hits for infinite time! :(

Comment: @SumanKumar Simply invert the last two operators (`tap` & `switchMap`). I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still not working. even if the response.complete is true after 3-4 calls, we have unstoppable calls.

Comment: i tried with do while loop. It was an horrible idea. I have rephrased the question if it might help you more ?

Comment: @SumanKumar sorry, got a little bit confused about my operators. I have edited my code, you can [see it working here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsnd8z).

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked.. (y) 
Just a minor addition, we have to also get the last true value. i.e.. {complete: true, value:11}

I have added the code here -  
{ if(response.complete) {
        console.log(response);
        this.destructor$.next();
 }

Please update in the stackblitz.com

Comment: @suman I'm pretty sure anyone wanting to make a console log, knows how to make a console log, don't worry. And I'm not at work anymore, which means I can't edit the blitz be aise I created it on my work station. I'm glad it worked and suited your needs, if you consider your question to have been answered, please accept an answer to credit the author and close your question.

Comment: Also in the Above code, please modify the code - timer(0, response.callAfterMs). It will make the solution even more clear ! :)

Answer (score 1):

we can call our service at regular interval like this.

```
Observable
    .interval(2*60*1000)
    .timeInterval()
    .flatMap(() => this.bookFlightService.GetFlights(abc, def, ghi)
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Update:
If you are using pipeable operators (rxjs5 and above), simply pipe the operators instead of chaining them:

interval(2 * 60 * 1000)
    .pipe(
        flatMap(() => this.bookFlightService.GetFlights(abc, def, ghi)
    )
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data))

---

Try with timer from RxJS :

```
import { Subscription, timer, pipe } from 'rjxs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

subscription: Subscription;
statusText: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = timer(0, 10000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.myservice.checkdata())
    ).subscribe(result => this.statustext = result);
}
```

interval(10000) from RxJS is not appropriate, because it will start to emit value only after 10sec and not immediatly first time.

The timer(0, 10000), will emit value immediatly (0) and every 10sec (10000).

Comment: But our interval is also dynamic. It is not a fixed value. We get the interval from API itself in this.requestInterval = this.bookFlights[0].callAfterMs;

Comment: You shouldn't be using the deprecated way of chaining Observable methods like this anymore.

Comment: you can set the interval value dynamically.
first get your interval value ready and then load this service

Comment: @Jaykant And how to stop ? We also get the stop flag from API in this.requestComplete = this.bookFlights[0].complete;

Comment: @SumanKumar Well, you use pipe() for any observable you're using post RXJS 6 to link methods.

Comment: @ak.leimrey How to stop the interval as we get stop flag from API itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't that you don't know how to do an interval call, but how to end it.

Your answer is the method "takeUntil". 
That way you can declaratively end a subscribable.

```
private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();
...
this.httpClient.post(<shortened for brevity>).pipe(interval(1000), takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe((data: any) => {

// do something with your data. If you got the data from the backend, the flag that disables the subscribable you can do...
this.ngUnsubscribe.next(); 
})
```

The takeUntil Method will cease any subscription the moment a new value gets passed.